# How can i click on particular link based on specific range

Tags: rpa

My question is about automation anywhere,I want to extract data from table which has two columns first column contains link and second column contains value in range of 10 so my task is if the value of second column in between 5 to 7 then it should click to corresponding link of that value please answer.

Answer (score 0):

are you using an excel file? My best guess in case that is actually the case is to:

1. Extract the data table in a specific session name
2. Create a loop on your data table
3. Put a condition inside your loop that will look like that: if Excel Column(2) is lower or equal than 7 but higher or equal to 5, extract Excel Column (1)
4. Open the link in a browser

More context to your question would help clearly identifying your issue and how to fix it..

Comment: Thanks for answer I will try this

Comment: Alright, if this worked could you mark the answer as correct?